# Reset graph at the end of the loop :could not find function "device" error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate plots by looping, here is my code:

```
n <- unique(wide_data$Product.Code)[1:3]

for (i in n)

{


my.prod2 <- filter(tall_bind, Product.Code == i, Date > ymd("2012/04/01"))

dev.new()

mypath <- file.path("C:","R","SAVEHERE",paste("myplot_", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))

jpeg(file=mypath)

mytitle = paste("Plot for product", i)

p <- qplot(Date, Sold, data = my.prod2, geom = "line", main=mytitle, group = Model, colour = Model) + facet_grid(Model ~ .)

ggsave("myplot_", i, plot=p, device= "jpg" )

}
```

I get the following error for the above code:

> Saving 6.67 x 6.67 in image
>
> Error in ggsave("myplot_", i, plot = p, device = "jpg") :     could
>   not find function "device"

Earlier when I used dev.off() at the end of the loop, I found that though the graphs were being generated they were totally blank.

Could someone please help me understand where is the mistake in my code?

Comment: change device to jpeg or do `ggsave(paste0("myplot_",i,plot = p,".jpeg")`. I would suggest png over jpeg for plots

Comment: @infominer thank you for your reply but unfortunately I am still getting an error . Saving 6.67 x 6.67 in image
Error in grDevices::png(..., width = width, height = height, res = dpi,  : 
  filename too long in png() call

Comment: I am a beginner in R, and hence I am having issues understanding these errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave out the dev.new() and jpg() commands, and also your arguments to ggsave() are incorrect. This should work:

```
n <- unique(wide_data$Product.Code)[1:3]
for (i in n) {
    my.prod2 <- filter(tall_bind, Product.Code == i, Date > ymd("2012/04/01"))
    mypath <- file.path("C:","R","SAVEHERE",paste("myplot_", i, ".jpg", sep = ""))
    mytitle = paste("Plot for product", i)
    p <- qplot(Date, Sold, data = my.prod2, geom = "line", main=mytitle, group = Model, colour = Model) + facet_grid(Model ~ .)
    ggsave(filename = mypath, plot = p)
}
```

What you did was creating a new default graphics device, typically a plotting window, then a jpeg graphics device, i.e. a file. Then you tried to make ggplot2 to plot to directly to file using ggsave, i.e. using its own (jpg) device, and not using either of the two graphics devices you created.

The error, however, was because you gave ggsave the wrong arguments. But even with the right arguments, you would still have ended up with additional unused graphics windows and files through the `dev.new()` and `jpeg()` commands. I suggest some extra reading of the help (e.g. type `?ggsave` at the r console).

Typically, when using ggplot2 you do not need to worry about `dev.new`, `jpeg` and the like. `qplot` or `ggplot` and `ggsave` should do all you need.

Comment: @ ROLO thank you very much for the solution and also the explanation.It is working well now, I also understood my mistake.